# Merge folders as branches when doing git svn clone

Tags: git-svn

How do we use the git svn clone to create multiple directories as branches and retain the branch name as is.

Here is the current svn structure

- svn/url/projectrootfolder/code

  - Subfolder1
  - Subfolder2
- svn/url/projectrootfolder/code_1
- svn/url/projectrootfolder/code_2
- svn/url/projectrootfolder/code_3

Run the following command with branches parameter (ignore code_2 and code_3)

`echo svnpassword | git svn clone "svn/url/projectrootfolder" --trunk=code --branches=code_1 --no-metadata --authors-file="authors.txt" --prefix="svn/" --preserve-empty-dirs --placeholder-filename=.gitkeep --username svnreader ProjectLocalFolder`

Check branch status

`git branch -a`

shows

```
* Master 
remotes/svn/Subfolder1
remotes/svn/Subfolder2
remotes/svn/trunk
```

I have only about a weeks worth experience with git and I assumed that the comamnd would create local branch code_1. But I don't see code_1 anywhere and the subfolders within the main project folder as branches. All the documentations I read seemed to indicate that git svn clone would achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This repository has "non-standard" layout — there's no `branches` subdir; there's no `trunk` subdir.

To explain what the options do (you assumed it incorrectly); suppose we had an repo structured like this (another non-standard layout, for the sake of example):

```
.
├── deployed-copies
│   ├── tag-01
│   │   ├── docs
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── test
│   ├── tag-02
│   │   ├── docs
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── test
│   └── tag-03
│       ├── docs
│       ├── src
│       └── test
└── latest-code
    ├── docs
    ├── src
    └── test
```

Notice that by structure, this is *almost the standard layout* except with customized names: `trunk` → `latest-code`, `branches` → `deployed-copies`. (svn "tags" are not really tags in git terms.)

So, in this example, you'd use `git svn clone --trunk=latest-code --branches=deployed-copies`. It would create 4 git branches, `svn/trunk`, `svn/tag-01`, `svn/tag-02`, `svn/tag-03` — and these will show in `git branch -a`.

Notice how this is different from your repo. I'm saying `--branches=deployed-copies` — not `--branches=deployed-copies/tag-01` ! This is incorrect: `--branches=code_1`; the flag accepts the relpath of the *parent directory* — the one which stores all the branch-dirs — and is called `branches/` in the standard layout.

---

Now, how to fix this? My advice would be:

- study the [manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), meticulously; especially, the [config-only options section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_config_file_only_options);
- edit the `[svn-remote "..."]` section in `.git/config`.

By far, not all non-standard svn layouts are possible to configure via the commandline flags to `git svn clone`. The most branch mapping flexibility is achieved by editing the config.

Answer (score 1):

@ulidtko - While I had figured I would have to go the config file route, thanks for clearing the understanding on the parent path. Even though I had read the documentation multiple times, this bit did not register and that was the missing link.

Merging this info and from other links I was able to arrive at the following course of actions that achieved what I needed.

1. To initiate the project with the trunk

`echo svnpassword | git svn clone "svn/url/projectrootfolder" --trunk=code --no-metadata --authors-file="authors.txt" --prefix="svn/" --preserve-empty-dirs --placeholder-filename=.gitkeep --username svnreader ProjectLocalFolder`

2. Add remote origin

```
git remote add origin git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/<<url>>
```

3. 

```
git fetch
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main master
git pull --rebase
git push origin HEAD:main
```

4. Modify the .git/origin file and add this line to the svn-remote section

```
branches = /{code_1,code_2}/:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

5. 

```
git fetch
```

6. The remote branches on svn should now show.
7. Process with checking out/switching and then pushing those branches individually into git.

This seems to have done it for me.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you succeeded. I believe that the `branches =` line also accepts the `*` glob, so you can write `branches = code_*:refs/remotes/svn/code_*`. And another nitpick: a *remote* called `branches` doesn't make sense to me, maybe you'd correct that. Otherwise, great job! Happy to have helped at least somewhat.